# Subtract two Date fields of datatype 'Date' and output in Hours. Did tried many formulas found online

Tags: formula, date

So I have two Date fields of type **Date** which will populate date using field updates by Workflows. Formula used - **Today()**  *// Note: I also tried using Now()*

I have a third field formula field of Return Type **Text**
`IF(Date_1__c>CloseDate, 
TEXT( 
(ROUND( MOD ((CloseDate - Date_2__c)*24,24),0) 
)), 
TEXT( 
(ROUND( MOD ((CloseDate - Date_2__c)*24,24),0) 
)))`
// I know I used same logic in the If-else; its just a test.

I needed the output in Hours. **Note:** I am receiving 0 as the output on the formula field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
(floor((CloseDate - Date_2__c)*24))
+
(((((CloseDate - Date_2__c)*24)-floor((CloseDate - Date_2__c)*24))*60)/100)
```

1st statement looks at # of hours only (ex: from 24.5 to 24). 
2nd takes the amount, removes the hours (ex: 24.5 to .5), and convert the decimals to minutes (ex: .5 to 30).

Comment: So I used just the first statement since I only needed hours and on testing I got 408.00 as the output. Where Closed Date was 7/30/2015 and Date 2 was 7/13/2015

Comment: Its correct, 17 days =408 hours, Do you need total hours or business hours?

Comment: Exactly what output do you want?

Comment: Sorry my bad! its good !